# SQL MaxSum query selecting incorrect value for a column

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have this SQL query (I'm using MySQL 8.0.35):

```
SELECT MAX(su) as value, activity_id, user_id, u.faculty_id AS faculty_id
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(s.distance) as su, s.activity_id as activity_id, s.user_id as user_id, s.date
            FROM submission s
            WHERE s.week = 2 AND s.accepted = 1 AND s.season_id = 859
            GROUP BY s.date, s.user_id, s.activity_id
    ) as sums
INNER JOIN user u ON user_id = u.id
GROUP BY activity_id;
```

What it does is: calculate the MAX SUM of distance, and fetch the "other" related columns.
In the result, there can be multiple rows (ideally one per activity).

However, it returns incorrect values for the "faculty_id" column.

I've tried putting the INNER JOIN on user table inside of the nested SELECT, using several different WHERE clauses, but nothing seems to return the correct result.

Partial user table:

[image: Partial user table]

Partial submission table:
[image: Partial submission table]

With this data, I expect the result to be:

| value | activity_id | user_id | faculty_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 743 | 265 | 3375 |
| 456 | 744 | 265 | 3375 |

However, the result I'm getting is (notice the faculty_id):

| value | activity_id | user_id | faculty_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 743 | 265 | 3373 |
| 456 | 744 | 265 | 3375 |

Comment: Important reading when you're going to abuse GROUP BY in this way : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html *(In short, don't do this; the behaviour is arbitrary and non-deterministic)*

Comment: Please read ; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my link in the comments above, abusing GROUP BY in this way returns arbitrary and non-deterministic results for the columns you neither aggregate nor group by.

Instead, the normal approach to "greatest-n-per-group" is to use ROW_NUMBER()...

```
WITH
  sub AS
(
  SELECT
    SUM(s.distance) as su,
    s.activity_id as activity_id,
    s.user_id as user_id,
    s.date
  FROM
    submission s
  WHERE
        s.week = 2 
    AND s.accepted = 1
    AND s.season_id = 859
  GROUP BY
    s.date,
    s.user_id,
    s.activity_id
),
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY activity_id
          ORDER BY su DESC
    )
      AS su_rank
  FROM
    sub
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted AS s
INNER JOIN
  user   AS u
    ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE
  s.su_rank = 1
```